# Is there a design pattern for logic performed on multiple event listeners

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, event-listener

I have logic that is performed on steps on multiple different events.
for example some logic is done on mousedown which changes some shared state that mousemove uses which also changes some shared state that finally mouseup uses.
for example it might look something like this

```js
function handleMouseDown(){
...
setState1()
...
setState2()
}
function handleMouseMove(){
...
consumeState2
...
consumeState1
setState3()
...
}

function handleMouseUp(){
...
consumeState3
...
}
```

The problem is that I feel that dependancy between the logic performed in those 3 events is implicit, which is in my opinion makes it hard to figure out what the code does especially if you considered that I have more than one task performed the same way.
So my question is there a design pattern for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's simple enough not to call it a design pattern. You just use a common state (an object in our case) for you event handlers. Always wanted to implement dragging with a proxy so here it is.

The updated version with drag & resize handles is here:
[How can I make it so that the divs don't get out of the purple div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531761/how-can-i-make-it-so-that-the-divs-dont-get-out-of-the-purple-div/76533863#76533863)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('div.container');
const draggable = document.querySelector('div.draggable');

const move = (x, y) => {

  x = state.fromX + (x - state.startX);
  y = state.fromY + (y - state.startY);

  // don't allow moving outside the container
  if (x < 0) x = 0;
  else if (x + draggable.offsetWidth > container.offsetWidth) x = container.offsetWidth - draggable.offsetWidth;
  
  if (y < 0) y = 0;
  else if (y + draggable.offsetHeight > container.offsetHeight) y = container.offsetHeight - draggable.offsetHeight;
  
  draggable.style.left = x + 'px';
  draggable.style.top = y + 'px';
};

const listen = (op = 'add') => 
  Object.entries(listeners).slice(1)
    .forEach(([name, listener]) => document[op + 'EventListener'](name, listener));

const state = new Proxy({}, {
  set(state, prop, val){
    const out = Reflect.set(...arguments);
    const ops = {
      startY: () => {
        listen();
        const style = getComputedStyle(draggable); 
        [state.fromX, state.fromY] = [parseInt(style.left), parseInt(style.top)];
      },
      dragY: () => move(state.dragX, state.dragY),
      stopY: () => listen('remove') + move(state.stopX, state.stopY),
    };
    // use a resolved Promise to postpone the move as a microtask so
    // the order of state mutation isn't important
    ops[prop] && Promise.resolve().then(ops[prop]);
    return out;
  }
});

const listeners = {
  mousedown: e => Object.assign(state, {startX: e.pageX, startY: e.pageY}),
  // here we first provide dragY to check that the order of props is not important
  mousemove: e => Object.assign(state, {dragY: e.pageY, dragX: e.pageX}),
  mouseup: e => Object.assign(state, {stopX: e.pageX, stopY: e.pageY}),
};

draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', listeners.mousedown);
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div.draggable{
  position: absolute;
  padding:30px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background:#ddd;
  cursor:move;
  user-select: none;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
}
div.container{
  left:15px;
  top:15px;
  background: #111;
  border-radius:4px;
  width:calc(100% - 30px);
  height:calc(100% - 30px);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="draggable">Draggable</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, I ended up doing something similar but with classes. I put the shared data as static properties and a static method for each event type. worked just fine.

Comment: @SandStone updated the answer to include a constraining container DIV. just for fun

Comment: @SandStone hehe, a more advanced version with resizing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531761/how-can-i-make-it-so-that-the-divs-dont-get-out-of-the-purple-div/76533863#76533863