# How to move and resize DIVs in a parent DIV container without overflowing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
  let isSelecting = false;
let selectionStartX, selectionStartY, selectionEndX, selectionEndY;
let selectionRectangle;
let draggedElements = [];
const widgets = document.querySelectorAll('.widgets');
const widgetContainer = document.getElementById('widget-container');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const header = event.target.closest('.widget-header');
  if (header) {
    const widget = header.parentElement;
    // If the clicked widget is not selected
    if (!widget.classList.contains('selected')) {
      // deselect all widgets 
      widgets.forEach((widget) => {
        widget.classList.remove('selected');
      });
      // and only drag the clicked one
      draggedElements = [widget];
    } else {
      // otherwise drag the selected 
      draggedElements = Array.from(widgets).filter((widget) => widget.classList.contains('selected'));
    }

    draggedElements.forEach((widget) => {
      const shiftX = event.clientX - widget.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const shiftY = event.clientY - widget.getBoundingClientRect().top;

      function moveElement(event) {
        const x = event.clientX - shiftX;
        const y = event.clientY - shiftY;

        widget.style.left = x + 'px';
        widget.style.top = y + 'px';
      }

      function stopMoving() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
      }

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveElement);
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopMoving);
    });

    return;
  }

  const isWidgetClicked = Array.from(widgets).some((widget) => {
    const widgetRect = widget.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      event.clientX >= widgetRect.left &&
      event.clientX <= widgetRect.right &&
      event.clientY >= widgetRect.top &&
      event.clientY <= widgetRect.bottom
    );
  });

  if (!isWidgetClicked && event.target !== selectionRectangle) { // Check if the target is not the selection rectangle
    isSelecting = true;
    selectionStartX = event.clientX;
    selectionStartY = event.clientY;
    selectionRectangle = document.createElement('div');
    selectionRectangle.id = 'selection-rectangle';
    selectionRectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
    selectionRectangle.style.border = '2px dashed blue';
    selectionRectangle.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(selectionRectangle);

    // Remove selected class from widgets
    widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      widget.classList.remove('selected');
    });
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    selectionEndX = event.clientX;
    selectionEndY = event.clientY;

    let width = Math.abs(selectionEndX - selectionStartX);
    let height = Math.abs(selectionEndY - selectionStartY);

    selectionRectangle.style.width = width + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.height = height + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.left = Math.min(selectionEndX, selectionStartX) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.top = Math.min(selectionEndY, selectionStartY) + 'px';
    selectionRectangle.style.display = 'block';

    widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      const widgetRect = widget.getBoundingClientRect();
      const isIntersecting = isRectangleIntersecting(widgetRect, {
        x: Math.min(selectionStartX, selectionEndX),
        y: Math.min(selectionStartY, selectionEndY),
        width,
        height,
      });
      if (isIntersecting) {
        widget.classList.add('selected');
      } else {
        widget.classList.remove('selected');
      }
    });
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isSelecting) {
    isSelecting = false;
    selectionRectangle.remove();
  }
});

function isRectangleIntersecting(rect1, rect2) {
  return (
    rect1.left >= rect2.x &&
    rect1.top >= rect2.y &&
    rect1.right <= rect2.x + rect2.width &&
    rect1.bottom <= rect2.y + rect2.height
  );
}
```

```css
  #selection-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999;
}

.widgets.selected {
  outline-color: blue;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: dashed;
}

.widgets {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 2px solid #212128;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 166px;
  min-height: 66px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  image-resolution: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.widget-header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #040c14;
  outline-color: white;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
}

#purple-div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <div id="widget1" class="widgets" style="left: 50px; top: 50px;">
    <div id="widget1header" class="widget-header"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="widget2" class="widgets" style="left: 150px; top: 150px;">
    <div id="widget2header" class="widget-header"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="widget3" class="widgets" style="left: 250px; top: 250px;">
    <div id="widget3header" class="widget-header"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="purple-div"></div>
```

I want the widgets to be restricted by the purple div and I don't know how to do it. The mouse also has to always be dragged from where it started to drag, that means if it hits the border, the mouse has to go back to where it was dragging the widget from in order to move(while having the mouse down, that means dragging).

Comment: If you find my answer useful you could upvote it (the arrow up) and accept it (the checkbox). that way i'll be rewarded with points and be motivated to help you in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continued from my answer: [Is there a design pattern for logic performed on multiple event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76420174/is-there-a-design-pattern-for-logic-performed-on-multiple-event-listeners/76420340#76420340)

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');

draggables.forEach(elem => {
  makeDraggableResizable(elem);
  elem.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
     const maxZ = Math.max(...[...draggables].map(elem => parseInt(getComputedStyle(elem)['z-index']) || 0));
     elem.style['z-index'] = maxZ + 1;
  });
});

function makeDraggableResizable(draggable){

  const move = (x, y) => {

    x = state.fromX + (x - state.startX);
    y = state.fromY + (y - state.startY);

    // don't allow moving outside the container
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    else if (x + draggable.offsetWidth > container.offsetWidth) x = container.offsetWidth - draggable.offsetWidth;

    if (y < 0) y = 0;
    else if (y + draggable.offsetHeight > container.offsetHeight) y = container.offsetHeight - draggable.offsetHeight;

    draggable.style.left = x + 'px';
    draggable.style.top = y + 'px';
  };

  const resize = (x, y) => {

    x = state.fromWidth + (x - state.startX);
    y = state.fromHeight + (y - state.startY);

    // don't allow moving outside the container
    if (state.fromX + x > container.offsetWidth) x = container.offsetWidth - state.fromX;

    if (state.fromY + y > container.offsetHeight ) y = container.offsetHeight - state.fromY;

    draggable.style.width = x + 'px';
    draggable.style.height = y + 'px';
  };

  const listen = (op = 'add') => 
    Object.entries(listeners).slice(1)
      .forEach(([name, listener]) => document[op + 'EventListener'](name, listener));

  const state = new Proxy({}, {
    set(state, prop, val){
      const out = Reflect.set(...arguments);
      const ops = {
        startY: () => {
          listen();
          const style = getComputedStyle(draggable);
          [state.fromX, state.fromY] = [parseInt(style.left), parseInt(style.top)];
          [state.fromWidth, state.fromHeight] = [parseInt(style.width), parseInt(style.height)];
        },
        dragY: () => state.action(state.dragX, state.dragY),
        stopY: () => listen('remove') + state.action(state.stopX, state.stopY),
      };
      // use a resolved Promise to postpone the move as a microtask so
      // the order of state mutation isn't important
      ops[prop] && Promise.resolve().then(ops[prop]);
      return out;
    }
  });

  const listeners = {
    mousedown: e => Object.assign(state, {startX: e.pageX, startY: e.pageY}),
    // here we first provide dragY to check that the order of props is not important
    mousemove: e => Object.assign(state, {dragY: e.pageY, dragX: e.pageX}),
    mouseup: e => Object.assign(state, {stopX: e.pageX, stopY: e.pageY}),
  };

  for(const [name, action] of Object.entries({move, resize})){
    draggable.querySelector(`.${name}`).addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
      state.action = action;
      listeners.mousedown(e);
    }); 
  }

}
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.draggable{
  position: absolute;
  padding:45px 15px 15px 15px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background:#ddd;
  user-select: none;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  min-width:200px;
}
.draggable>.move{
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background:#bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  cursor:move;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0;
}
.draggable>.resize{
  cursor:nw-resize;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:16px;
  width:16px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, #777 50%, transparent 50%)
}
.container{
  left:15px;
  top:15px;
  background: #111;
  border-radius:4px;
  width:calc(100% - 30px);
  height:calc(100% - 30px);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="draggable"><div class="move">draggable handle</div>Non-draggable content<div class="resize"></div></div>
    <div class="draggable" style="left:230px;"><div class="move">draggable handle</div>Non-draggable content<div class="resize"></div></div>
</div>
```