# Resizing selected elements with js using mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resize, drag

I'm currently working on an app that involves selecting elements by dragging and resizing them using mouse movements. The selection part, where the chosen elements are stored in canvas.selected.elements, is working perfectly fine. However, I'm facing some challenges when it comes to resizing the selected elements.

Here's the relevant code snippet that handles the resizing logic:

```
editor_container.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (canvas.mousedown && canvas.grabbed.resize) {
    const x = (e.clientX - canvas.mousedown.clienX) * (1 / canvas.scale);
    const y = (e.clientY - canvas.mousedown.clienY) * (1 / canvas.scale);
    resizeElement(x, y, canvas.grabbed.resize, canvas.selected.elements);
  }
};
```

In the code above, I'm attempting to resize the selected elements within the resizeElement function based on the mouse movement. However, it seems like something is not working as expected, and the resizing doesn't produce the desired results.

```
const resizeElement = (clientX, clientY, direction, elements) => {
    let x, y, x1, x2, y1, y2, width, height;
    switch (direction) {
        case "nw":
            elements.forEach(element => {
                x = element.x; 
                y = element.y; 
                width = element.w; 
                height = element.h; 
                x1 = x + clientX; 
                y1 = y + clientY; 
                x2 = (x - x1) + width; 
                y2 = (y - y1) + height;
                let l = (x2 * (1 / canvas.scale)) >= 0; let t = (y2 * (1 / canvas.scale)) >= 0;

                if (l) { element.style.left = x1 + 'px'; element.style.width = (x2) + 'px'; }
                if (t) { element.style.top = y1 + 'px'; element.style.height = (y2) + 'px'; }
            }); break;
        case "ne":
            elements.forEach(element => {
                x = element.x; 
                y = element.y; 
                width = element.w; 
                height = element.h; 
                x1 = x + clientX; 
                y1 = y + clientY; 
                x2 = width + clientX; 
                y2 = (y - y1) + height;
                let t = (y2 * (1 / canvas.scale)) >= 0;
                if (t) { element.style.top = y1 + 'px'; element.style.height = (y2) + 'px'; }
                element.style.width = x2 + 'px';
            }); break;
        case "sw":
            elements.forEach(element => {
                x = element.x; 
                y = element.y; 
                width = element.w; 
                height = element.h; 
                x1 = x + clientX; 
                y1 = y + clientY; 
                x2 = (x - x1) + width; 
                y2 = height + clientY;
                let l = (x2 * (1 / canvas.scale)) >= 0;
                if (l) { element.style.left = x1 + 'px'; element.style.width = (x2) + 'px'; }
                element.style.height = y2 + 'px';
            }); break;
        case "se":
            elements.forEach(element => {
                x = element.x; 
                y = element.y; 
                width = element.w; 
                height = element.h; 
                x1 = x + clientX; 
                y = y + clientY; 
                x2 = width + clientX; 
                y2 = height + clientY;
                element.style.width = x2 + 'px'; element.style.height = y2 + 'px';
            }); break;
        default: return null;
    }
};
```

I suspect that the issue lies within the resizeElement function itself, where I need to implement the logic to properly resize all the selected elements. Currently, the function receives the x and y values of the mouse movement, the resizeType, and the array of selected elements (canvas.selected.elements).

Could you please help me identify the problem and suggest a solution for resizing the selected elements based on the mouse movement? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

This is what ive managed to get:
Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/ghyvzLcw/1/

(video):
https://www.veed.io/view/f777f01e-60ae-4e7a-bbe3-8bb25556571d?panel=share

and this is what Im trying to:

https://www.veed.io/view/8fbeef80-58c9-4bb0-a297-3b85928a88b5?panel=share

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move and resize DIVs in a parent DIV container without overflowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531761/how-can-i-make-it-so-that-the-divs-dont-get-out-of-the-purple-div)

Comment: I've already done some resizing on movable elements, check it here and don't forget to upvote if it's useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531761/how-can-i-make-it-so-that-the-divs-dont-get-out-of-the-purple-div/76533863#76533863

Comment: Can you share codepen instead of fiddle?