# Resizing of the container is lagging

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the resizable container from the bottom like here, on stackoverflow editor. I found
Marek's solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64323700/22212216 and it works as intended but there is one issue - I have to resize veery slowly to not loose the resizing, otherwise it stops to being resized. Could anyone have a look at the code and tell what can be changed?

Comment: Please put the code you're talking about in your question, preferably via the `[<>]` button. Furthermore, what have you tried yourself? Some effort is required, not just *"Go fix this code"* Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move and resize DIVs in a parent DIV container without overflowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531761/how-to-move-and-resize-divs-in-a-parent-div-container-without-overflowing)