# How to keep a draggable div inside parent border with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a draggable div made with JS but I want it to only be draggable inside it's parent border, whats the best way to do this?

I've seen a couple people ask the same thing but I only know pure JS yet and they were using frameworks.

The idea is that it will look like a window inside another window, the tiny window shouldn't go outside the bigger one, and not go above bigger's header too.

```
 <div class="window">
   <header class="window-header">
   </header>
   <div class="window-content">
     <div class="little-window">
       <header class="little-window-header">
       </header>
       <div class="little-window-index">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

```
.window {
    width: 45%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
}


.window-header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
}



.window-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    background-color:lightblue;
}




.little-window{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}



.little-window-header {
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```
 var windowContent = document.querySelector("window-content")
 var littleWindow = document.querySelector(".little-window");
 var offsetX, offsetY;

 var move = (e) => {
   littleWindow.style.left = `${e.clientX - offsetX}px`;
   littleWindow.style.top = `${e.clientY - offsetY}px`;
 }


 littleWindow.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
   offsetX = e.clientX - littleWindow.offsetLeft;
   offsetY = e.clientY - littleWindow.offsetTop;
   document.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
 });

 document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
   document.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pv591wb6/35/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move and resize DIVs in a parent DIV container without overflowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76531761/how-to-move-and-resize-divs-in-a-parent-div-container-without-overflowing)