# How to stop the chain after trigger addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, chain

So I have an addEventListener function which will trigger the addEventListener in two different buttons when click on it. When click the first buttons, it will then insert **player-1** text or second button to insert **player-2** text into **athlete-ranking** id innerHTML.

The function will trigger everything inside but I don't know how to stop the the other event for happening when either **player-1** or **player-2** button is clicked. I want to work both ways too. Meaning click the **player-2** event so the **player-1** event won't be triggered.

JS

```
rank.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (some code) {
    const insertName = document.getElementById('athlete-ranking');
    // First Event
    const obtainFirstName = document.getElementById('player-1').innerHTML;
    insertName.innerHTML = obtainFirstName

    // Second Event
    const obtainSecondName = document.getElementById('player-2').innerHTML;
    insertName.innerHTML = obtainSecondName
   } else {
   some code
   }
)}
```

HTML

```
<button id="player-1">Player one</button>
<button id="player-2">Player two</button>
<span id="athlete-ranking"></span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a design pattern for logic performed on multiple event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76420174/is-there-a-design-pattern-for-logic-performed-on-multiple-event-listeners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, why not you can achieve the desired behavior by using a single event listener with conditional statements to differentiate between the two buttons.

```js
const insertName = document.getElementById('athlete-ranking');
const player1Btn = document.getElementById('player-1');
const player2Btn = document.getElementById('player-2');

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target === player1Btn) {
    // First Event: Insert player-1 text into athlete-ranking span
    insertName.innerHTML = player1Btn.innerHTML;
  } else if (e.target === player2Btn) {
    // Second Event: Insert player-2 text into athlete-ranking span
    insertName.innerHTML = player2Btn.innerHTML;
  } else {
    // Handle other cases if needed
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="player-1">Player one</button>
<button id="player-2">Player two</button>
<span id="athlete-ranking"></span>
```

Comment: I understand that splitting into 2 addEventListener worked but I want to stick everything into one addEventListener, if that is possible.

Comment: I have updated the code. Check it now.